# php array and recursive function

Tags: php, arrays, function, recursion, array-merge

hello stackoverflow :),

I block on this problem for a few days I think that the solution is with a recursive function but I cannot create it.

my main problem is that the source data is random, I can not determine neither the order nor the amount of data.

I would like to combine several array to be able to prepare my request in db

for example I can receive a table

```
array: {
       color_id: [3,4],
       size_id: [11, 6, 7]
}
```

and I would like to convert it to

```
color_id[ 
     3 => size_id[11, 6, 7],
     4 => size_id[11, 6, 7],
],
```

to simplify nothing it is possible to have x array, example

```
array: {
       color_id: [3,4],
       size_id: [11, 6, 7],
       x_id: [8, 9],
}
```

to

```
color_id[ 
     3 => size_id[
                 11 => x_id[8, 9],
                 6  => x_id[8, 9], 
                 7  => x_id[8, 9]
                 ],
     4 => size_id[
                 11 => x_id[8, 9],
                 6  => x_id[8, 9], 
                 7  => x_id[8, 9]
                 ],
],
```

I have to be able to cover all possibilities,
Thanks for your help

Comment: Without code you can expect answers without code.  It is not obvious what `color_id[ ... ]` is supposed to be. Is it supposed to be `[ "colour_id": [ 3 => ["size_id" => [11, 6, 7]], ...]]`?

Comment: Dont know what you want to do with the result array, but in this way it's gonna cause trouble. In the first result `6,7 and 11` are array values, in the second they are key-values.